# Google doc from html - inconsistently including images

Tags: google-api

I have a simple script that converts a relatively short string of HTML into a google doc using the googleapis library from NPM.  This has a small amount of text and a couple of `<img>` tags.  The problem I have is that sometimes 1 image is in the final document, sometimes a different one, sometimes 2 of the three, and rarely all 3 or none.

I feel like I'm missing a step of waiting for something asynchrynous but I can't figure out what it might be.  Here is my code:

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v2', auth });

        drive.files.insert({
          media: {
            mimeType: 'text/html',
            body: html // html is a simple string of html with some <img> tags
          },
          convert: true
        })
          .then(res => {
       // here I export the file as a PDF and do stuff with that
        });
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about your question. Can I ask you about your issue?

Comment: Sure, feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample HTML data for replicating your issue?

Comment: Sure `<p>sample text</p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/oFJHmA0.jpg" /><img src="https://i.imgur.com/cVwaG7l.png" />`.  This is a minimal example that is pared down of all formatting and excess content but does elicit the inconsistent missed-image issue I've been having.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when your sample HTML is used, the Google Document converted from the HTML has the text of `sample text` and the 2 images. This is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. So can you provide the whole script including the sample HTML for replicating your situation? Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can do, please add it to your question.